# Coding a left/right object movement C# script for android phones in unity

Tags: c#, unity, android, controllers

I have 2 spheres and a cube on screen.

I'm experimenting to make a 'left/right movement script' for the cube so that when I touch the left sphere, the cube moves left-wards and when I touch the right sphere, the cube moves right-wards.

I have 2 scripts. I have attached **SphereLeft.cs** to left sphere and **SphereRight.cs** to right sphere.

Any pointers on how to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are just one script, assign it to the cube
***TargetSlideControl.cs***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TargetSlideControl : MonoBehaviour {

public int SPEED = 1;
public Transform leftTrigger;
public Transform rightTrigger;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    // If Mobile
    if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer){
         if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
           checkTouch(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
         }
     }else if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor){ // Else if Desktop
         if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
           checkTouch(Input.mousePosition);
         }
     }
}

private void checkTouch( Vector2 pos ) {
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( pos );
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
        if(hit.collider.transform  == leftTrigger) {
            SlideLeft();
        } else if(hit.collider.transform  == rightTrigger){
            SlideRight();
        }
    }
 }

// Call Translate on this transform passing SPEED * Direction * deltaTime

public void SlideLeft() {       
    this.transform.Translate( SPEED * Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime, Space.World );
}

public void SlideRight() {
    this.transform.Translate( SPEED * Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime, Space.World );
}
}
```

Assign the spheres in the editor to the TargetSlideControl script:

[image]

ENJOY!

Comment: Is it working in your editor/windows Desktop/Android phone ? I did what you said but the spheres are not receiving the touches on touching. I tried on an android phone, windows desktop. Not working.

Comment: Sure it works! Have you dragged the spheres in the editor to leftTrigger and rightTrigger in the script?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell you that the spheres need a collider applied

Comment: No problem. I applied collider and ticked on 'Is Trigger' the cube. Accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

## This is a simple guessing game

import random

## Generate a random number between 1 and 10

secret_num = random.randint(1, 10)

## Ask the user to guess the number

guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))

## Keep asking the user to guess until they get it right

while guess != secret_num:
if guess < secret_num:
print("Too low, try again.")
else:
print("Too high, try again.")
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))

## If they get it right, print a congratulations message

print("You got it! The secret number was", secret_num)

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question that was asked.